# What's the difference between XElement and XDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, vb.net

What is the difference between `XElement` and `XDocument` and when do you use each?

Comment: [This MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx) gives us clear idea about Querying an XDocument vs. Querying an XElement.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

[XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) represents a whole XML document. It is normally composed of a number of elements.

[XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) represents an XML element (with attributes, children etc). It is part of a larger document.

Use XDocument when working with a whole XML document, XElement when working with an XML element.

For example - `XElement` has a `HasAttributes` property indicating whether any attributes exist on the element, but an `XDocument` doesn't, as such a property is meaningless in the context of a whole XML Document.

Comment: _XElement has no load method_: seems incorrect, see [Load(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298435.aspx) and [other overloading `Load` methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx).

Answer (score 21):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx):

> Note that you only have to create
>   XDocument objects if you require the
>   specific functionality provided by the
>   XDocument class. In many
>   circumstances, you can work directly
>   with XElement. Working directly with
>   XElement is a simpler programming
>   model.
>
> XDocument derives from XContainer.
>   Therefore, it can contain child nodes.
>   However, XDocument objects can have
>   only one child XElement node. This
>   reflects the XML standard that there
>   can be only one root element in an XML
>   document.

Answer (score 18):

Here's a practical example from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx) which makes it clear. Assume you have this in *test.xml* file:

```
<Root>
    <Child1>1</Child1>
    <Child2>2</Child2>
    <Child3>3</Child3>
</Root>
```

1. **With XDocument** if you do this:

   ```
   foreach (var element in XDocument.Load("test.xml").Elements())
       Console.WriteLine(element);
   ```

   You get this back:

   ```
   <Root>
       <Child1>1</Child1>
       <Child2>2</Child2>
       <Child3>3</Child3>
   </Root>
   ```

   To get the value at `Child1` node, you will have to do:

   ```
   var child1 = XDocument.Load("test.xml").Element("Root").Element("Child1").Value;
   ```

   Or

   ```
   var child1 = XDocument.Load("test.xml").Root.Element("Child1").Value;
   ```
2. **With XElement** if you do this:

   ```
   foreach (var element in XElement.Load("test.xml").Elements())
       Console.WriteLine(element);
   ```

   You get this back:

   ```
   <Child1>1</Child1>
   <Child2>2</Child2>
   <Child3>3</Child3>
   ```

   To get the value at `Child1` node, you will do:

   ```
   var child1 = XElement.Load("test.xml").Element("Child1").Value;
   ```

In short, `XElement` ignores the root node while `XDocument` doesnt. Roughly, `XDocument.Root = XElement`, or `XDocument.Root.Elements() = XElement.Elements()`. Both derive from `XContainer`. Another minor difference is that `XElement` implements `IXmlSerializable` which I dont think matters mostly. `XElement` would be enough for vast majority of cases where you just want to query the sub nodes. The name confuses me though, so I prefer to use `XDocument`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the MSDN article [LINQ to XML vs. DOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-xml-vs-dom#working-directly-with-xml-elements), under the subheading "Working Directly with XML Elements":

> When using LINQ to XML, you use the XDocument class only if you want to add a comment or processing instruction at the root level of the document.