# difference between XElement and XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the difference between XElement and XDocument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879868/whats-the-difference-between-xelement-and-xdocument)

What is the difference between `XElement` and `XDocument`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3879868/whats-the-difference-between-xelement-and-xdocument

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By design, the difference (in usage) is very small.

You sometimes need a full XDocument, if you want access to the processing instructions etc.

But the following is fine (for most purposes):

```
XElement doc = XElement.Load("file.xml");
```

While a similar construct with XmlElement would not work.

Answer (score 8):

The difference is that an `XElement` type represents an XML fragment while the `XDocument` type represents an entire XML document with all associated meta-data.

Answer (score 8):

XDocument has a [Declaration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.declaration.aspx), [Root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root.aspx) while XElement is a single node.

Comment: can i have multiple nodes in XElement

Comment: yes, it can have multiple child nodes.